# How to access db2 sequence in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to access db2 sequence in Spring?
Need to access a sequence to generate an id and pass it to an insert statement using spring using jdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define a bean that handles the sequence. Something like this:

```
<bean id="incrementer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.DB2SequenceMaxValueIncrementer">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="incrementerName" value="YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME" />
</bean>
```

Then, you have to wire this bean to the bean that's going to invoke it. e.g.:

```
@Autowired
private DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer incrementer;
```

Finally, you use the sequence bean to get a value:

```
Long identifier = incrementer.nextLongValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried queryForInt() with the SQL `select sequence.nextval from dual`?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#queryForInt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)